# Rewriting Cubic Equations

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

It is possible to rewrite the equation $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ as $y^3+3hy+k=0$ by setting $y=x+a/3$

How do you find the coefficient h in the equation $y^3+3hy+k=0$?

Comment: see here i hope this helps http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html

Comment: Try it!  Set $y=x+a/3$ in $y^3+3hy+k$, multiply it out, and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put $$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=\left(y-\frac a3\right)^3+a\left(y-\frac a3\right)^2+b\left(y-\frac a3\right)+c=$$$$=y^3-ay^2+\frac {a^2}3y-\frac {a^3}{27}+ay^2-\frac {2a^2}3y+\frac {a^3}9+by-\frac {ab}3+c=$$and collect terms$$=y^3+3\left(\frac {3b-a^2}9\right)y+\frac{-2a^3-9ab+27c}{27}$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
x^3+ax^2+bx+c=\left( \color{red}{x+\frac{a}{3}} \right)^3+\left( \color{blue}{b-\frac{a^2}{3}} \right) \left( \color{red}{x+\frac{a}{3}} \right)+\left( \color{orange}{c-\frac{ab}{3}+\frac{2a^3}{27}} \right)=0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

If you change the (0,o) origin to the Inflection point of cubic equation , you will have that form 
$$y=x^3+ax^2+bx+c \\y'=3x^2+2ax+b\\y''=6x+2a=0 \to x=-\frac{a}{3}$$ you must change $$x \mapsto x-\frac{a}{3}$$
$$y=f(x)=y=x^3+ax^2+bx+c \to \\(x-\frac{a}{3})^3+a(x-\frac{a}{3})^2+b(x-\frac{a}{3})+c\\=x^3-3x^2\frac{a}{3}+3x(\frac{a}{3})^2-(\frac{a}{3})^3+ax^2-2ax\frac{a}{3}+\frac{a^3}{9}
+bx-\frac{ba}{3}+c$$note that $-3x^2\frac{a}{3}$ cancel with $x^2a$ and you will have 
$$x^3+x(\frac{a^2}{3}-2\frac{a^2}{3}+b)+(-(\frac{a}{3})^3+\frac{a^3}{9}-\frac{ba}{3}+c)$$ that is the form which you need it .

look an example : $$y=x^3+3x^2+5x-1 \\y''=6x+6=0 \to x=-1\\\to\\x \mapsto x-1\\apply \\Y=(x-1)^3+3(x-1)^2+5(x-1)-1\\=x^3-3x^2+3x-1+3x^3-6x+3+5x-5-1\\=x^3+2x-4$$